# How to customize the Lock Screen App of Windows Phone 8.1 like Live LockScreen?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am developing a `Windows Phone 8/8.1` Apps, I am able to customize the background of the lock screen and etc. But when I saw the app `Live LockScreen beta` by Microsoft I found its to be very good and inspire me that I can customize my `lockscreen` similar kind with standard clock customized and much more improve features.

However I don't know what API it's used, I search in internet - no help.

Any idea how can I get some API so that I can customize my lock screen Apps in Windows Phone, No background change API, but other features like Text, Clock etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I hope you're aware that, there's no such API being published yet which contains those features like in the `Live LockScreen Beta` as of now.

Comment: I am aware but it's sad, I thought if someone can guide me, if I am wrong. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: @Debhere hope we could receive something positive in the future!